# Artifactory: REST API bad design

Tags: rest, api, repository, artifactory

When making a `PUT` request to create a new (local/remote/virtual) repository, the REST API of Artifactory will return:

- status `200` when creation is successful
- status `400` with the keywords `already exists` in the response content if the resource already exists

**However**, when performing the same operations on **users/groups/permissions**, the response is `201` in both cases, whether the resource

- exists or
- has just been created

Response content is the same also!

Isn't this a bad api design?

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between the REST API's.

The Repository creation is marked as "Create Repository" for the PUT call and the update repository is done by using POST.

In the Users / Groups / Permissions, the REST API, using PUT, is used to "Create or **Replace** User" as you can see in [JFrog Artifactory Wiki page for REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-CreateorReplaceUser).

For that reason, even if the user exists in Artifactory, you will get a 201 as a reply to the REST API command will "replace" the existing user.

Comment: Yes but isn't this inconsistent? How the client is supposed to know whether the security resource already existed? IMHO the api should have kept a common / uniform approach in all resource CRUD operations and have consistent mappings (e.g. `201` --> successful creation, `40x` --> Already exists etc). I also think `400` which corresponds to `Bad Request` used in case of existing repository resource is too generic (it could be returned for several other reasons causing a `Bad Request`). `403` or `409` seem more appropriate.